# Django pass a url kwarg into a form.Form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to get initial values for a form.Form class form from url.

urls.py

```
path('nueva/<client_id>/', new_check_view, name='nueva valoración'),
```

views.py

```
def new_check_view(request, client_id):
    my_form = NewCheckForm()
    # print (client_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        my_form = NewCheckForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            Check.objects.create(**my_form.cleaned_data)
        else:
            print(my_form.errors)
    
    context = {
    "form": my_form
    }
    return render (request, 'checks/new-check.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class NewCheckForm(forms.Form):
    user_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label='Nombre',
        queryset= Client.objects.all(), 
        initial=client_id,
        )
```

However, I don't get how to pass that kwargs from the view to the class form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to use [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) param. For your code:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def new_check_view(request, client_id):
    client = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=client_id)
    my_form = NewCheckForm(initial={'user_id': client})
```

Remember to remove `initial=client_id` from `NewCheckForm`

Comment: `get_object_or_404(Client, pk=client_id)` was not necessary. Only with `client = client_id` worked. Thanks!

Comment: You are right. But you don't want to see error 500 on your site.

Comment: Juan, por qué no funciona con 404? No tiene sentido.